# Porque la variable para saber quien es MÁS JOVEN no funciona. Es un programa en el que una de las cosas que busco es saber la edad del mas Joven

Tags: java

Porque la variable para saber quien es MÁS JOVEN no funciona. Necesito ir comparando edades para obtener la de la persona mas joven, al acabar el programa me sale un valor de 0. En cambio saber la variable EDAD DEL MAYOR si me funciona. ////////// No se si estoy utilizando la forma mas adecuada de resolver este problema pero creo que mi solucion esta bien planteada. De vd si alguien me esta leyendo porfavor ayuda es que no puedo mas de verdad, una respuesta aunque sea de consuelo xfa;)

```
 package matrizEdades;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class matrizEdades {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int componentes;
        int edad = 0;
        int edadJoven = edad;
        int edadMayor = edad;
        int sumaEdades = 0;
        int media;
        
        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad de componentes (Entre 5 y 10): ");
        componentes = sc.nextInt();
        
        while(componentes<5 | componentes>10) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una CANTIDAD VALIDAD (Entre 5 y 10): ");
            componentes = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        for(int i = 0;i<componentes;i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la edad de la Persona " + (i+1));
            edad = sc.nextInt();
            if(edad > edadMayor) {
                edadMayor = edad;
            }
            if(edad < edadJoven) {
                edadJoven = edad;
            }
            sumaEdades = sumaEdades + edad;
        }
            media = sumaEdades / componentes;
            
            System.out.println("La edad total es: " + sumaEdades);
            System.out.println("La media de la edad del grupo es: " + media);
            
            if(edad < edadJoven) {
                System.out.println("La edad del mas joven es: " + edad);
            }else {
                System.out.println("La edad del mas joven es: " + edadJoven);
            }
            
            if(edad > edadMayor){
                System.out.println("La edad del mas mayor es: " + edad);
            }else {
                System.out.println("La edad del mas mayor es: " + edadMayor);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque has declarado la variable a 0, entonces siempre que la edad introducida por consola sea mayor a 0, nunca se va a actualizar.

```
int edadJoven = edad;
```

En ese momento, edad tiene un valor de 0, de ahí la asignación del valor 0 a la variable.

Para hacer el ejercicio de forma más profesional, puedes declarar la variable edadJoven como null. Ejemplo:

```
Integer edadJoven = null;
```

Es importante que tengas en cuenta como se está declarando, para explicartelo de la forma más clara posible, el valor null en Java no puede ser declarado en tipados primitivos como int. Entonces lo que se utiliza para ello es una clase llamada Integer, a esta misma si le puedes pasar números y el valor null.

De está forma te aseguras que jamás va a haber un valor mayor o menor al primer valor que introduzcas por consola, para ello haremos lo siguiente:

```
    if (edadJoven == null) {
        edadJoven = edad;
    } else if (edad < edadJoven) {
        edadJoven = edad;
    }
```

Hay formas mejores incluso de hacer esto, pero si estás aprendiendo Java desde el principio es la mejor práctica para entender la lógica del funcionamiento de este código.

Ahora, se puede presentar el siguiente caso, y es que formes el condicional de la siguiente forma:

```
if (edad < edadJoven || edadJoven == 0) {
    edadJoven = edad;
}
```

Pero aquí tendrías un problema gordo, y es que si introduces la siguiente secuencia de respuestas: 17, 10, 0, 13... el valor de edadJoven pasa a ser 13 después de recibir el valor 0 por como está montado el condicional, con esto hago referencia a una de las respuestas que se ha proporcionado para que se tenga en cuenta.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda :)

Cheers!

Comment: Un tipo primitivo son solo datos. Lo que llamamos objetos, por otro lado, son solo punteros a donde se almacenan los datos,basado en ello no puedes usar ```null``` en ```int```solo para objetos ```Integer```

Comment: @Dramaturgo estás en lo cierto, escribiendo me he puesto en modo Typescript y se me ha colado, ahora mismo lo corrijo para que el código sea el correcto gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola La inconsistencia es simple al momento de validar la edad menor, cuando intentas comparar la edad digitada con la edad guardada asi

```
if(edad < edadJoven) {
```

la variable edadJoven es igual a 0 y la edad digitada va ser un numero mayor.

```
Ejemplo:  edad(20) < edadJoven(0)
```

Solución:

```
if(edadJoven > edad || edadJoven == 0) {
   edadJoven = edad;
}
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, me sigue apareciendo al final "edad del mayor 0"

Comment: Adicionando esta otra validación if(edadJoven > edad || edadJoven == 0) iniciaras la edad menor con la primera edad ingresada.

Comment: @ANDRESCABAÑASPECHERO Enviare una copia de un ejemplo en mi maquina local funcionando, el único error evidente es al inicializar la variable menor la cual intentas comparar con el valor digitado explicado en la primera respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

la variable edadJoven no puede ser 0 ya que todos los numeros que tu ingreses nunca sera menores a 0 asi que esa varible terminara con valor 0 ,bien pues para hallar el menor de los numeros ingresados la variable edadJoven debe ser mayor a todos los numeros ingresados podemos asignarle edadMayor pero eso implica hacer otro for, por lo que le asignamos un valor mayor a edadJoven para que el algoritmo funciones,ojo no es necesario las condicionales para imprimir quien es mayor o menor

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrizEdades {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int componentes;
        int edad = 0;
        int edadJoven = 100;
        int edadMayor = edad;
        int sumaEdades = 0;
        int media;
        
        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad de componentes (Entre 5 y 10): ");
        componentes = sc.nextInt();
        
        while(componentes<5 | componentes>10) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una CANTIDAD VALIDAD (Entre 5 y 10): ");
            componentes = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        for(int i = 0;i<componentes;i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la edad de la Persona " + (i+1));
            edad = sc.nextInt();

            if(edad > edadMayor) {
                edadMayor = edad;
            } 

            if(edad < edadJoven) {
              edadJoven = edad;
            }

            sumaEdades = sumaEdades + edad;
        }

            media = sumaEdades / componentes;
            
            System.out.println("La edad total es: " + sumaEdades);
            System.out.println("La media de la edad del grupo es: " + media);
          
            System.out.println("La edad del mas joven es: " + edadJoven);
            System.out.println("La edad del mas mayor esa: " + edadMayor);
        
    }
}
```